# What are the use cases for inline vertical-align:middle?

Tags: html, css

When vertically aligning inline-elements with *vertical-align:middle* from a visual point of view the resulting alignment seems to be slightly off. This effect comes from the following discrepancy:

- In the perception of most people the vertical middle point for text naturally seems to be either the middle of an **uppercase** letter (aka cap-height) or the middle of an 'upwards-reaching' lowercase letter like 'h' or 'f' (aka x-height + ascender)
- The html/css standards defines the vertical middle point as the middle of a small **lowercase**-letter like 'x' (aka the x-height)

I suspect that the html/css standard was defined this way for some kind of valid reason. 
So what was the thought process behind this decision, and how does it translate to concrete use cases for this kind of vertical alignment behaviour?

Comment: This does not really sound on-topic at SO. The question seems to be of the form “is there a problem for this solution?” rather than a practical programming (or HTML/CSS coding) question.

Answer (score 3):

This can be summed up with the following image

[image]

Allocated space for a font typically includes space for all derivations. This includes accenting. With the considerations of descenders and capital/ascenders, The middle point vertically falls within the centerpoint of a lowercase x (x-height), which is roughly (descender+ascender/2) - or the half-way point between the tail of a 'y' and the tip of a 'h'.

This is different to the *mean line* of capital letter height+baseline/2. It is this difference which accounts for the visual discrepancy- however, reference the image: if the median line were taken as the vertical middle, the result would be a typeface with additional vacant space at its bottom resulting from the (roughly) 25% shift up the y-axis. In terms of alignment, as this excess space would form part of the underlying typeface the misalignment could not be controlled out by altering line-height.

Comment: You should draw some freehand lines and arrows marking the x-height.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - added revised image

Comment: That's not freehand! You need more [freehand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)!

Comment: I'm aware that the middle of the x-height roughly corresponds to the middle of the font size. However from a perception point of view the descender doesn't seem to count into the font size (neither do accents). I don't understand how you say that the reasoning behind this behaviour are things like accents, yet your image illustrates the middle of the font size (**excluding** accents). Can you explain some more?

Comment: @BillAskaga - updated answer with a more detailed illustration

Comment: How does this answer the question (“What are the use cases for inline vertical-align:middle?”)?

Comment: It answers the part: "I suspect that the html/css standard was defined this way for some kind of valid reason. So what was the thought process behind this decision"